# read numpy compressed file using matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

i have a large compressed matrix data saved in a numpy compressed file data.npz.Now i want to load and read it in matlab. can anybody suggest a better solution for the same.Thanks in advance.
i searched

Comment: Uncompress it and then load it into MATLAB using a solution from the duplicate target

Comment: how can u please suggest a solution reference code

Comment: In MATLAB, write `unzip('data.npz');` This will uncompress your npz file and give you an `npy` file. You can read this `npy` file using a solution mentioned in the duplicate target